# Problem with Azure in Microsoft learning path module (Kubernetes)

Tags: azure, kubernetes, .net-core, microservices

I am just doing this module of Microsoft course:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/learn/modules/microservices-aspnet-core/

I created an azure subscription and tried to run the script given in unit 2.
Something is going on in the console, but at some point it shows something like this:

```
Getting credentials for AKS...
(ResourceNotFound) The Resource 'Microsoft.ContainerService/managedClusters/eshop-learn-aks' under resource group 'eshop-learn-rg' was not found. For more details please go to https://aka.ms/ARMResourceNotFoundFix
Code: ResourceNotFound
Message: The Resource 'Microsoft.ContainerService/managedClusters/eshop-learn-aks' under resource group 'eshop-learn-rg' was not found. For more details please go to https://aka.ms/ARMResourceNotFoundFix

Installing NGINX ingress controller
error: You must be logged in to the server (the server has asked for the client to provide credentials)
error: You must be logged in to the server (the server has asked for the client to provide credentials)
error: You must be logged in to the server (the server has asked for the client to provide credentials)

Getting load balancer public IP

 > kubectl get svc -n ingress-nginx -o json | jq -r -e '.items[0].status.loadBalancer.ingress[0].ip // empty'

error: You must be logged in to the server (the server has asked for the client to provide credentials)
Waiting for load balancer IP...
```

Am I doing something wrong? Strictly followed instructions.

Edit:
I think problem is with VM, not AKS.

```
> az aks create -n eshop-learn-aks -g eshop-learn-rg --node-count 1 --node-vm-size Standard_D2_v5 --vm-set-type VirtualMachineScaleSets -l centralus --enable-managed-identity --generate-ssh-keys -o json

ERROR: (BadRequest) The VM size of AgentPoolProfile:nodepool1 is not allowed in your subscription in location 'centralus'.
```

Comment: It happens to me too...

Answer (score 0):

You need to log in :

```
az login
az account set --subscription <YOUR SUB ID>
az aks get-credentials --resource-group <AKS RG> --name <AKS NAME>
```

Comment: az aks get-credentials --resource-group <AKS RG> --name <AKS NAME> gives ResourceNotFound error "The Resource 'Microsoft.ContainerService/managedClusters/eshop-learn-aks' under resource group 'eshop-learn-rg' was not found"

Answer (score 0):

The 'CentralUS' location doesn't accept new VM with the type of subscription you have.
You need to use another location.

To do that, you need to declare a variable 'defaultRegion' in the bash shell (ex.: `declare defaultRegion=eastus`) before executing `wget`